Excel SSO Add-In Pane not starting
I have installed webpack and webpack-cli globally, and I'm used the yeoman to install a sample sso plugin.
However whenever I try to start the application (npm start) an error comes back:
ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Software\Prototypes\ExcelSSOJS3'
resolve './src' in 'C:\Software\Prototypes\ExcelSSOJS3'
Any ideas on why this is coming up?


I was able to figure out that this was something that wasn't being downloaded on my machine. I reinstalled and it worked.
